# Active Perl nmake

Tags: xml, perl

i'm having loads of problem in trying to install CPAN Modules. Using the cpan.exe, I try to install a module with, for example, "install XML::DOM" but I end up hitting a wall. when the install finishes it says dmake.exe is NOT OK,

```
It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!


cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install mingw
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 23 Oct 2013 11:17:03 GMT
Warning: Cannot install mingw, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /mingw/

to find objects with matching identifiers.


cpan> exit
Lockfile removed.

C:\Perl>cpan -i XML::DOM

It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!

CPAN: Term::ANSIColor loaded ok (v4.02)
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.34)
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 23 Oct 2013 11:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::DOM'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.84)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.06)
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz o
k
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.90)
XML-DOM-1.44/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentType.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentFragment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttlistDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Notation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Attr.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ProcessingInstruction.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Entity.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Document.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Parser.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Node.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ElementDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/EntityReference.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CharacterData.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMException.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/PerlSAX.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Comment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Element.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/XMLDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CDATASection.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMImplementation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Text.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttDef.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/BuildDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/t/
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_noexpand.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_template.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_text.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_encode.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.ent
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_documenttype.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.dtd
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/build_dom.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/FAQ.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/Changes
XML-DOM-1.44/MANIFEST
XML-DOM-1.44/META.yml
XML-DOM-1.44/CmpDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/minutes.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/REC-xml-19980210.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/BUGS
XML-DOM-1.44/CheckAncestors.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/XML-Parser-2.31.patch
XML-DOM-1.44/Makefile.PL
XML-DOM-1.44/README
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4404)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120921)

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz


It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite XML::Parser::PerlSAX 0.07 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::RegExp 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for XML-DOM
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.80)
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz       ----
    XML::Parser::PerlSAX [requires]
    XML::RegExp [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX'
Running make for K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KM\KMACLEOD\libxml-perl-0.08.tar.
gz ok
libxml-perl-0.08/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Subs.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/CanonXMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Sample.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/XMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ActionTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/PatternTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/Amsterdam.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/MatchName.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ToObjects.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/SAX2Perl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Perl2SAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/ESISParser.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/PerlSAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Parent.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Visitor.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/CreatingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/interface-style.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/modules.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0-adv.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/PerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/mirror.sh
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/index.html
libxml-perl-0.08/Changes
libxml-perl-0.08/MANIFEST
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/MyHandler.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/perlsax-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/esis-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/t/
libxml-perl-0.08/t/schema.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/stream.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/xp_sax.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/subs.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/canon_xml_writer.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/amsterdam.t
libxml-perl-0.08/ChangeLog
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl-0.08.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/Makefile.PL
libxml-perl-0.08/README

  CPAN.pm: Building K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz


It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for libxml-perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.39)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'XML::RegExp'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.g
z ok
XML-RegExp-0.04/
XML-RegExp-0.04/META.yml
XML-RegExp-0.04/test.pl
XML-RegExp-0.04/README
XML-RegExp-0.04/Changes
XML-RegExp-0.04/MANIFEST
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/RegExp.pm
XML-RegExp-0.04/Makefile.PL

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz


It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::RegExp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\XML-DOM-1.44-SiwM
Kc

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX => 0.07' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.
tar.gz' failed when processing 'KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz' with 'make =>
NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9725)
Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::RegExp => 0' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz' fail
ed when processing 'TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continui
ng, but chances to succeed are limited.
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

C:\Perl>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-DOM/ shows you should be able to instal XML::DOM by `ppm XML-DOM`

But if  http://code.activestate.com/ppm/MinGW/ doesn't have MinGW for your build of perl
You can get one from http://sourceforge.net/projects/perlmingw/

Or if you (should) read  [How to install CPAN modules into ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl) 
Which explains how you can go with nmake... by installing   [Download Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK Web Install from Official Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6510)  
And making sure to call `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\SetEnv.Cmd" /XP64 /RETAIL` before you try `cpan module` or even `cpanm module`

Comment: I download "Download Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK Web Install from Official Microsoft Download Center " but what should i do ?

Comment: Read the readme it explains what to do: http://sourceforge.net/projects/perlmingw/files/Compiler%20for%2064%20bit%20Windows/